# Install startport mv: cannot move './starport' to '/usr/local/bin/starport': Permission denied

Tags: blockchain, cosmos-sdk

[image]

> mv: cannot move './starport' to '/usr/local/bin/starport': Permission denied

Answer (score 9):

I know this comes late but it can help some other people.

Starport installation requires write permission to the /usr/local/bin/ directory. If you get such error, do this

run

```
curl https://get.starport.network/starport | bash
```

then run

```
sudo mv starport /usr/local/bin/
```

to move to the local bin directory with sudo.

Answer (score 3):

Just run the script in terminal `sudo curl https://get.starport.network/starport! | sudo bash` command download binary and move to /usr/local/bin/

Answer (score 2):

Checkout **Write permission Section** from **Install Support Docs**

https://docs.starport.network/guide/install.html

`curl https://get.starport.network/starport | bash` -> **For write access**

`sudo mv starport /usr/local/bin/` -> **To move it into sub-root folders**